# Class locals as predicates pre C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, predicate

The following code compiles without errors/warnings when being built with C++11 mode, using GCC and Clang. However if I attempt to compile without C++11 mode and error occurs in the 2nd scope.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct astruct
{
   int v;
};

struct astruct_cmp0
{
   bool operator()(const astruct& a0, const astruct& a1) {
     return a0.v < a1.v;
   }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<astruct> alist;
   {
      // Works - no errors
      std::stable_sort(alist.begin(),alist.end(),astruct_cmp0());
   }

   {
      struct astruct_cmp1
      {
         bool operator()(const astruct& a0, const astruct& a1) {
           return a0.v < a1.v;
         }
      };

      // error: template argument uses local type 'astruct_cmp1'
      std::stable_sort(alist.begin(),alist.end(),astruct_cmp1());
   }

   return 0;
}
```

My question is: What was the C++11 change that allows the local struct definition? could someone please point me to the specific section in the standard (section 9.8 perhaps?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++03 function local types are not viable template arguments. In C++11 function local types are viable template arguments. The key quote in C++03 is 14.3.1 [temp.arg.type] paragraph 2:

> The following types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter:
>
> - a type whose name has no linkage
> - ...

In C++11 this constraint is removed.

The relevant section on when linkage is defined is 3.5 [basic.link] (in both standard) which is fairly long and points to entities without linkage by exclusion, paragraph 8 in C++03:

> Names not covered by these rules have no linkage. ...

Types defined within a function are not listed in "these rules".